# What is the difference between a vector and a matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix

I've seen the following statements in a help file:

```
xL = [-6 -6];
xU = [6 6];
```

I didn't understand whether `xL` and `xU` are vectors or matrices. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

In MATLAB terminology, both *vectors* and *matrices* are arrays of numerical values.

Technically, a vector is a form of a matrix having one row or one column (read about [`isvector`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isvector.html) and [`ismatrix`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismatrix.html) commands for more information).

Practically, however, matrices are usually referred to in the documentation as having *at least* 2 columns and 2 rows, so I would rather call `xL` and `xU` *vectors*.

Answer (score 9):

A vector is a 1-dimensional matrix, either a vertical vector (N × 1) or horizontal vector (1 × N). Vectors are a subclass of matrices, so every vector is a matrix. `xL` and `xU` are horizontal (1 × N) vectors and therefore they are also matrices.